# Text Classification - Multiple Training Datasets

Tags: python, text-classification

Would there be “dilution” of accuracy if I train the same text classification model with multiple training datasets? For example, my end users would be providing (uploading) their own tagged CSVs to train the model and use the trained model in the future. The contexts of datasets would be different - L&D, Technology, Customer Support, etc.

If yes, how do I have a “separate instance or model” for each user?

I am using Python and would possibly use Gradio or Streamlit as the UI. Open to advice.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to train a model with "multiple training sets" since a model is trained with only one training set. I assume that you mean concatenating several datasets as training set? Anyway if the goal is for the user to provide their own training set and train their own model, why are you also training a model yourself? The training set will of course have an impact on performance.

Comment: I was initially looking at having users assigned their own space and one model for the sake of "simplicity". But yes, agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using huggingface's zero-shot classification.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).